# highcharts-react-native drilldown chart

Tags: react-native, highcharts, drilldown

I'm trying to create a drilldown chart using `highcharts-react-native` taking reference from here -
http://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/v1o8dga9/3/

I have taken the same object from above reference and provided it to my component's return -

```
        return (
            <View>
                <HighchartsReactNative
                    styles={styles.container}
                    options={this.state.chartOptions}
                />
            </View>
        )
```

I can see the chart on my Android simulator but drilldown doesn't work. I tried `Click` event with a alert and its working, means click is possible on react-native.

To make drilldown work on web we have to import drilldown.js. How can we import drilldown.js in react-native?

Comment: Have you already checked and tried methods from the API? https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native#modules

Comment: Hi @SebastianWędzel, you mean adding `module` (const modules = ['highcharts-more']) will add `drilldown` to the page?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel - just tried but no difference. Created this variable (const modules = ['highcharts-more','drilldown'];) and applied it to  <HighchartsReactNative options={this.state.chartOptions} modules={modules}/>